# Объединение репозиториев в один

Tags: git, github

Использую github. Допустим, есть ряд репозиториев, которые связаны общей темой, и, чтобы не захламлять общий вид профиля, пришла в голову мысль закинуть их в один репозиторий. Грубо говоря, чтобы выглядело что-то вроде: есть репозиторий и в нем остальные:

```
-main repo
--1st repo
--2nd repo
--3rd repo
--readme.md
```

Никаких настроек не нашел, нашел только трансфер на другой github.

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так:

В репозитории №1 все содержимое переносил в подпапку /Project1/

В репозитории №2 все содержимое переносил в подпапку /Project2/

В репозитории №3 все содержимое переносил в подпапку /Project3/

Далее в в локальной копии репозитория №1 по очереди добавлял остальные хранилища в качестве remote и делал pull. В итоге получил проект, у которого в корне были папки:

/Project1/

/Project2/

/Project3/

push отправил всю историю всех проектов в общий репозиторий.

После этого репозитории 2 и 3 были удалены за ненадобностью.